# want to make master buil.xml file which call all project's build.xml file

Tags: ant, build-automation

Each subproject contains its own buildfile, and the master project has a master
buildfile capable of building all of the subprojects.

I want to know how to make this master build file which can call all other build file in sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `subant` task:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html